# Access helper element value onRendered

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there a way to access the value a helper function outputs using onRendered. I'm trying to insert a style into a div based on a formula a helper generates.

```
Template.test.onRendered(function () {
    var e1 = document.getElementById("mered");
    var helperfunction = this.find(helperFunction);
    e1.style.width = helperfunction;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a Session in the helper.

```
Template.test.onRendered(function () {
    var e1 = document.getElementById("mered");
    if(Session.get('elementWidth')) {
        new_width = Session.get('elementWidth');
        e1.style.width = new_width + "px";
    }
});

Template.test.helper({
    helperFunction: function(){
        var some_width = 20;
        if(some_width){
            Session.set('elementWidth', some_width);
        }else{
            Session.set('elementWidth', undefined);
        }
        return some_width;
    }
});
```

HTML Code to check the generated width

```
{{#if helperFunction}}
    {{helperFunction}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This only works when I have `console.log(some_width);` in the helper and `console.log(e1);` in onRendered. It's a little strange.

Comment: Yeh, if I remove the console.log it doesn't work. It also doesn't work on a mobile.

Comment: Are you calling the `helperFunction` in the template?

Comment: U can add px after the number